# Format Excel From Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, excel-2013

I am in need to add a new row above Cell 1 in my workbook.  I typed out the below syntax which I believe is correct, but I am getting an error of:

> Object does not support this property or method

When the syntax hits the second line of my `with` block - `.Rows("1:1").Select`

What do I need to alter in order for this syntax to execute as expeceted?

```
Function AdddFormatting()
  Dim ExportRecordSet As DAO.Recordset
  Dim excelWS As Object, excelWS2 As Object
  Dim xl As Object
  Dim wb As Object
  Dim TemplateWB As String

  Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  TemplateWB = "C:\Test\Testwb.xlsx"
  Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
  Set excelWS = wb.Worksheets(1)
  excelWS.Name = "AddedFromCode"
  Set excelWS2 = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
  excelWS2.Name = "AddedFromCode2"
  xl.Application.Visible = True

  With wb
    .Sheets(1).Activate
    .Rows("1:1").Select
    'Using this syntax throws the same error
    '.Rows(1).Select
    .Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Range("A1:H1").Select
    .Selection.Merge
    .ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "This is the text that will display as the header"
    .Range("A1:H1").Select.Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Range("A1:H1").Select.Font.Size = 15
    .Range("A1").Activate
  End With
End Function
```

**EDIT**
Per the comment posted by @user2676140 I altered my `with` block from `with wb` to `with excelWS` which now throws the same error on line 3 - this one:

```
.Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: I think the syntax on that line is wrong...  .Rows(1).Select is the way to select a full row

Comment: Visit this link for more information: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/entire-rows-columns.html

Comment: If I alter the syntax to be .Rows(1).Select I get the same error message.

Comment: Record a macro to see how it's done...

Comment: @JeremyThompson - if I record the macro in Excel - the syntax I have posted is what is produced.  I am manipulating Excel from Access - and I do not believe there is a way to record a macro showing that VBA in Access 2013, but I thought adding the With wb block would allow me to use Excel VBA from within Access.

Comment: I suggest referencing the Excel DLL (unmanaged so use the ActiveX not the PIA). With early binding you will get intellisense and be able to diagnose the problem much easier than with late binding

Comment: Try using excelWS.Rows(1).Select

Comment: @JeremyThompson Is it possible to use the .NET PIAs from within VBA?

Comment: The VBA in Excel and the VBA in Access is exactly the same. The only difference is which global objects are available by default in Excel (e.g. `Excel.Application`) and which global objects are available by default in Access (e.g. `Access.Application`). You can reference Excel objects either using late binding (as you are doing, with the `CreateObject` function) or using early binding, by adding a reference (**Tools -> References...**) to the Microsoft Excel object library, as @JeremyThompson notes. The `With` statement does something completely different -- it lets you call members on a ...

Comment: Huh, the Primary Interop Assemblies allow .Net to use the object model in Offices unmanaged apps. VBA has all the access to it's hosts object model. If you're programming Excel from Access use early binding by referencing the DLL  and not using CreateObject

Comment: @JeremyThompson Yes, so VBA has no need for the PIAs, and cannot use them.

Comment: No, VBA is unmanaged.

Comment: ..variable or expression without repeating the variable/expression over and over; in this case the `wb` variable. So instead of writing `wb.Sheets(1).Activate: wb.Rows("1:1").Select` you can write `With wb: .Sheets(1).Activate: .Rows("1:1").Select: End With`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax can def use some cleaning up but it should get you close to your desired output.  Post a comment with any issues that this still brings you and I will try to walk you through a fix.

```
excelWS.Activate
excelWS.Rows(1).Select
xl.Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
excelWS.Range("A1:H1").Activate
xl.Selection.Merge
xl.ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "This is the text that will display as the header"
excelWS.Range("A1:H1").Activate
xl.Selection.Font.Name = "Arial"
xl.Selection.Font.Size = 15
excelWS.Range("A1").Activate
```

->@StarsFlyFree FromCozyNights<- to only merge A1:H1 try changing this line:

```
excelWS.Range("A1:H1").Activate
```

to this ---->

```
excelWS.Range("A1:H1").Select
```

Comment: I took the freedom and removed the "With" statements completely, they only added "noise" to the code.

Comment: So close to what I need.  This merges all of Row 1 not just A1:H1 - can you fix?